# div間の隙間が埋まらない

Tags: css

div間の空白を消したいのですがmargin,paddingを設定しても消えません。この空白はどこからきているのでしょうか。解決方法をご回答よろしくお願いします。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CSS Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   </head>
<body>
<div class="list6">
        <ul>
            <li>PJ party</li>
            <li>potluck party</li>
            <li>Present travel ticket</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="list6-2">
        <ul>
            <li>Find internship</li>
            <li>bus tour</li>
            <li>Cone maze</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
body {
  background: rgba(186, 216, 228, 0.315);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
.list6 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: rgb(46, 64, 87);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  background: rgb(241, 143, 1);
  height: 100px;
}
.list6-2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: rgb(46, 64, 87);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  background: rgb(4, 139, 168);
  min-height: calc(50vh - 100px);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ul`のマージンですね。
`ul { margin: 0; }`で消えます。

Comment: 助かりました！ありがとうございます！